# Color print preview not showing UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiprintinteractioncntrler

In iPad print preview not showing UILabels. When I zoom in the print preview it showing properly.  When I changed UILabel `opaque` property to `true` it will change the UILabel's background to black and display on print preview. This is the code I used to show print preview.

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
printInfo.jobName = "Print"
printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplex.none
printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientation.portrait

printController.printPageRenderer = nil
printController.printingItems = nil
printController.printingItem = printUrl

printController.printInfo = printInfo
printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true

printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

When I change `UIPrintInfoOutputType.general` to `UIPrintInfoOutputType.grayscale` it will display the UILabels, but I need color print. Grayscale is only for black & white printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many ways to solve my problem, and finally I found a solution.

I changed the `opaque` property of UILabel to `true` and then changed the background color of UILabel to white. The problem was, the background color of UILabel was **Default**. So that, In print preview the background of UILabel was shown in black. If the background color of UILabel is **Default** or **Clear Color** it will show in black in print preview.

```
printLabel.isOpaque = true
printLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //Not Default or Clear Color
```